# Why can't Jest resolve a module that exists under node_modules?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app

I have a React app created using Create React App. I have the following component that I am trying to test using Jest:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'core-ui';

export const Example = () => {
  return (
    <div className="Example">
      <Button>Click me!</Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`Button` is inside the `core-ui` package, has a dependency on the `core-utils` package:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Logging } from 'core-utils';

export const Button = (props) => {
  logger.log('Rendering button');
  return (
    <button>
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
}
```

When I try to test this button using Jest, I get the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module 'core-utils' from 'Button.js'

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:221:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/core-ui/src/components/Button/Button.tsx:2:1)
```

Jest can't resolve the `core-utils` module even though it is located right under `node_modules`. Note that when I run the React app, it has no issues bringing up the component. So it's only Jest that can't resolve the `core-utils` module. Any ideas where the issue is and how to solve it?

Here's the Jest test for reference:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from 'enzyme';

import { Example } from './Example';

describe('<Example />', () => {
  let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Example />);
  });

  it('renders', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('div.Example')).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: are you using `jest-enzyme`?

Comment: I am not using jest-enzyme. The only enzyme related modules in my package.json are:  enzyme@3.9.0 and enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.10.0. Other than that I have typescript definition files: @types/enzyme@3.9.0" and @types/enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.0.5.

Comment: Please show jest config

Comment: The jest config is created by create-react-app using this code: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/createJestConfig.js. There is no additional Jest config that I am adding.